# Highlighting a Specific day in in ngx-daterangepicker-material than current day

Tags: angular, ngx-daterangepicker-material

I am using ngx-daterangepicker-material for my calendar.

```
<ngx-daterangepicker-material id="datePicker" [linkedCalendars]="linkedCal" (chosenDate)="chosenDate($event)"  [maxDate]="maxDateRange"
    [minDate]="minDateRange" [singleDatePicker]="false"></ngx-daterangepicker-material>
```

I have set the maxDateRange and minDateRange as well.

```
 maxDateRange = moment().subtract(1, 'days');
 minDateRange = moment().subtract(60, 'days');
```

The Current day is disabled here. But, the prev day is not getting highlighted/marked, Please let me how to do this.
[Current calendar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2u6g.png)